# Swap default selected select options with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a select box as follows

```
<select>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No" selected="selected">No</option>
<option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
<option value="So">So</option>
</select>
```

I would like

```
<select>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
<option value="Maybe" selected="selected">Maybe</option>
<option value="So">So</option>
</select>
```

*note default selection is now "Maybe" instead of "No"

I learned jquery before really getting comfortable with pure JavaScript. So im trying to learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assign an id to the select element:

```
<select id="choices">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No" selected="selected">No</option>
    <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
    <option value="So">So</option>
</select>
```

Then, access the options via the standard `options` array on `<select>` elements:

```
var choices = document.getElementById('choices');
choices.options[2].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign an `id` to the `select` element then do this:

```
var s = document.getElementById( 'select_box' );
s.options[ 2 ].selected = true;
```